# How to write result of union of column of two tables in select query in hive

Tags: bigdata, hiveql, hadoop2

I am writing Select statement in hive , but my requirement is to use one field in select query that comes after union of column from two tables . Tables joined have been used in the select query but I am more stuck with problem how to use union of column from two tables , Please refer SQl query below :

```
SELECT  t1.a ,  t2.b FROM tab1 inner join tab2 on ( t1.c = t2.c) inner join tab3 t3 on(t2.b = t3.b );
```

on above query I want below result but I am stuck here :

```
SELECT  t1.a ,  t2.b , (t1.d UNION t2.d ) FROM tab1 inner join tab2 on ( t1.c = t2.c) inner join tab3 t3 on(t2.b = t3.b );
```

I have tried writing subquery in select statement but seems not to be working as Hive does not support subquery within select statement . I have also tried writing with statement first and try to use the result in select statement but I also not seems to be working .

Comment: can you show some sample data and your expectation out of it?